Style Flex gap background on position sticky
I am using a position sticky within a CSS flexbox. However, on on scroll I would like the scrollable items to be hidden behind the sticky header part and don't want them to be see through. Is there any option to fix this, e.g. having another fixed element which is not taking any of the initial scroll space which is behind the sticky and in front of the scrollable elements?
See here: Row inbetween Header and Section in scroll area should be hidden



html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.view {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.stick-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.stick-section {
  position: sticky;
  top: 60px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
<div class="view">
<div class="row">Row Content before Header</div>
<div class="stick-header">Header</div>
<div class="stick-section">Section</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="stick-section">Section</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="stick-section">Section</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="stick-section">Section</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="stick-section">Section</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>
<div class="row">Row Content</div>




If the view container will always have a known background color you can use it to add colored layers around the sticky element.
outline: 4px solid #EEE; /* hide content around the corner */
/* 20px color from the top and 40px color from the bottom*/
border-image: conic-gradient(#EEE 0 0) 1/20px 0 40px/20px 0 40px;

Full code


html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.view {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.stick-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 4px solid #EEE;
  border-image: conic-gradient(#EEE 0 0) 1/20px 0 40px/20px 0 40px;
}

.stick-section {
  position: sticky;
  top: 60px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
<div class="view">
  <div class="row">Row Content before Header</div>
  <div class="stick-header">Header</div>
  <div class="stick-section">Section</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="stick-section">Section</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="stick-section">Section</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="stick-section">Section</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="stick-section">Section</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>
  <div class="row">Row Content</div>



Read my article to understand the border-image property: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2024/01/css-border-image-property/

Looks interesting, thanks! Does it also work on the Sections with the border-radius applied?

@TimNikischin yes
